# gfortran complains about too many arguments to ZABS

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I'm currently trying to build [this library](https://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/netlibfiles.pl?filename=/amos/zairy.f) so I can link it to my rust program.
Unfortunately gfortran gives me this error:

```
zairy.f:147:11:

147 |       AZ = ZABS(ZR,ZI)
|           1
Error: Too many arguments in call to ‘zabs’ at (1)
```

In every file that uses `ZABS` I don't know any thing of Fortran but it looks to me as if ZABS takes two arguments (zabs.f:1):

```
DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION ZABS(ZR, ZI)
```

I'm compiling it using these commands:

```
gfortran -c -o d1mach.o d1mach.f
gfortran -c -o dgamln.o dgamln.f
gfortran -c -o i1mach.o i1mach.f
gfortran -c -o xerror.o xerror.f
gfortran -c -o zacai.o zacai.f
gfortran -c -o zairy.o zairy.f
gfortran -c -o zasyi.o zasyi.f
gfortran -c -o zbknu.o zbknu.f
gfortran -c -o zdiv.o zdiv.f
gfortran -c -o zexp.o zexp.f
gfortran -c -o zkscl.o zkscl.f
gfortran -c -o zlog.o zlog.f
gfortran -c -o zmlri.o zmlri.f
gfortran -c -o zmlt.o zmlt.f
gfortran -c -o zs1s2.o zs1s2.f
gfortran -c -o zseri.o zseri.f
gfortran -c -o zshch.o zshch.f
gfortran -c -o zsqrt.o zsqrt.f
gfortran -c -o zuchk.o zuchk.f
gfortran -c -o zabs.o zabs.f
ar rv airy.a d1mach.o dgamln.o i1mach.o xerror.o zacai.o zairy.o zasyi.o zbknu.o zdiv.o zexp.o zkscl.o zlog.o zmlri.o zmlt.o zs1s2.o zseri.o zshch.o zsqrt.o zuchk.o zabs.o
```

I think I'm missing something in the commands.

How do I compile the library without errors?

Here is also some more information from [the original website](https://www.netlib.org/amos/index.html) of the source code.

Comment: `zabs` is also an intrinsic (taking one argument) function provided by gfortran. You can disable this extension by adding an option like `-std=f95` or you can modify the code to ensure the non-intrinsic procedure is used. We'll want a [mre] to provide useful advice.

Comment: Does adding the lines `External zabs` in the declaration part of zairy.f help, i.e. just above the `data` statements? Alternatively try adding `-std=f95` to the compile flags, but I fear that is less likely to work - a quick once over a couple of files suggests it is reasonably standard conforming old style Fortran ( and still so accepted), but I haven't been through in any kind of detail